# Native method to find duplicate column names in a pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that fetches an xml link from a table and parses it to a dict, this dict becomes a dataframe and their nested dicts also become dataframes, both get concatenated and so on. I attempted to make the code carefully parse every new column name with a unique name, but maybe I made an oversight somewhere and there may be duplicate column names somewhere, which might be stopping a final `pd.concat()` method from working in joining the dataframe I'm working on and the new I'm trying to join, so I get the error: `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

I could maybe create an empty list, iterate over the column names, if column name is already in the list I throw an error, otherwise I append it to the list, but maybe there's a native method to do that?

EDIT: I want to find duplicate column names in a single dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicate columns names in one dataframe (as you ask in your comment) you can use the `.duplicated()` method.

Something like that:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

The `duplicated()` method return a boolean array, with `True` or `False`. So if it is `False` then the column name is unique, if it is `True` then the column name is duplicated earlier. For example, if the returned value is `[False, False, True]`. The `True` is duplicated columns names.

Using `~` you change the boolean value to the opposite, so all `False` becomes `True`, etc. So, you will keep only the non duplicated columns.

If you just want to check if there is duplicated, you can simply use `any()` method:

```
any(df.columns.duplicated())
```

Hope it's help!

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my post was rather ambiguous, I meant I wanted to find duplicate column names in a single dataframe

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I'll update my answer!